# Maven goals doing cobertura analysis and install

Tags: maven, jenkins, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I'm using `Jenkins` and `Maven` to build some Java projects. Additionally I'm using `Cobertura` for coverage analysis. Therefore I've setup a Jenkins Maven build job and configured following goals:

```
clean cobertura:cobertura
```

That's working fine for coverage analysis but doesn't generate any jar output configured in the POM. I think it's this way because Maven goal `package` isn't in [Cobertura lifecycle](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/cobertura-mojo.html).

For getting jar files I tried changing it to

```
clean cobertura:cobertura install
```

That's doing the job but got another problem: every goal from `resources` to `test` is executed twice :( Console output looks like (removed detail lines)

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] >>> cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) > [cobertura]test @ HelloWorld >>>
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:instrument (default-cli) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] <<< cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) < [cobertura]test @ HelloWorld <<<
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ HelloWorld ---
```

**Is there a way to use `install` using results from phases `resources` to `test` from `cobertura`?**

In other words an output like

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] >>> cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) > [cobertura]test @ HelloWorld >>>
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:instrument (default-cli) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] <<< cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) < [cobertura]test @ HelloWorld <<<
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ HelloWorld ---
```

Additional info: changing POMs is not an option because they're not managed by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: there isn't. Using some trial and error I finally found a solution to live with:

Leaving Maven goals like

```
clean cobertura:cobertura
```

and adding a post build step executing Maven goal

```
install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

This way tests are not executed twice. `compile` and similar are executed twice but that's not that bad because Cobertura already compiled everything forcing Maven to skip this step.

Nota bene: `clean cobertura:cobertura install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` is not possible because `test.skip` switch has effect on both targets.